# Mongoose: series of custom instances

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

According to the documentation I can do such thing:

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });

animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = function (cb) {
  return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
}
```

Suppose I have another function:

`animalSchema.methods.owner` which filter if `animalScheme.owner` is xyz, so it modifies the search query to `{..., owner: xyz}`

Is it possible to use instance sequentially? and how can I achieve this?

```
var animalSchema.findSimilarTypes().owner("xyz") ?
```

any hint?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this doesn't work straight away because the original function `findSimilarTypes` does not return a schema object.

I'm guessing you're trying to do something to how jQuery works.